# How to handle subcomponents and properties created in runtime vs designtime?

Tags: delphi

I can' t realize this thing. I have a component in DELPHI that includes 2 other components: a Firemonkey Layout and inside of that an dynamic array of TLayout which includes a TRectangle.
This is achieved through the property BarNumber.

I have lots of problems about Design Time vs. Runtime behaviour, this is due to the DFM (FMX in Firemonkey) that stores the subcomponents as part of the Object.
Now. This is the code of the On Create part.

```
constructor TFluffyTable.Create(Owner: TComponent);
var
i: integer;
begin
  inherited Create(Owner);

  Width:=300;
  Height:= 160;
  BarNumber:=100;
  SetLength(Column, FBarNumber);
  for i := 0 to (FBarNumber-1) do
  begin
     Column[i]:= TColumn.Create(Self);
     Column[i].Name:= 'Column_' + IntToStr(i);
     Column[i].Parent:= Self;
     Column[i].Height:=Height;
     Column[i].Width:=Width/FBarNumber;
     Column[i].Align:= TAlignLayout.alMostLeft;
   end;
  end;
```

If I register the component and I use it in design time I get the correct number of bars displayed. But if I run the program with the component, I get twice the number of bars, since the EXE loads the values. I managed to solve this with

```
   if not (csDesigning in ComponentState) then
```

just before the for loop.
But I can't see, obviously, the BARS in design mode. Well I can stand that if this is the only solution. 
That's not over..!
For a strange reason, The only one place I can set my values for Width, Height and BarNumber is that part of code. If I set them in the object inspector they won't be considered and reset to default when I run the program.
(BarNumber is a variable which reads and writes on FBarNumber)

In short: I don't know how to handle and manage my component to make BarNumber and other properties to be set in design time, and to see the correct number of bars in Runtime.
Thank you so much.

Comment: you should accept the answers, if they are correct, I see all your questions you never accept..

Comment: i got the same problem with object created at design time by a simple component that i made

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar problem. I used stored property to avoid this problem.
Example:

```
constructor TMachine.Create(AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited;
  self.Width := 50;
  self.Height := 90;

  // create machine rectangle and set default properties
  FMachine := TRectangle.Create(self);
  FMachine.Parent := self;
  FMachine.Height := 50;
  FMachine.Align := TAlignLayout.alBottom;
  FMachine.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.red;
  FMachine.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Black;
  FMachine.Stroke.Thickness := 3;
  FMachine.Stored := false;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the component you create at design time will be stored in the fmx files. When you run the application you have twice controls, to resolve the problem you need to set the stored property to false to the sub objects of your component like this:

Column[i].Stored := False;

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that you are starting with 0 columns at runtime.
Just add something like:

```
for [i] = pred(length(column)) downto 0 do
begin
  column[i].free
end;
```

before you start making the columns.

Comment: mmm I tried, but it don't works. On runtime the values of the Column array are reset, so freeing them won't have effect. I used the Loaded Method along with csDesigning check to make sure that the bars are added only in runtime. It works, but It's still far from ideal. Thank you so much anyway..!